# Why am I getting an error in the GO init() method?

Tags: go, init

So I understand that in go, init() is a special method that can be used to initialize an object in a package. When I try to use this technique, I get an error that the variable is declared and not used. For example:

```
package fizzbuzz

var foo string

func init() {
    foo := "bar"
}
```

It seems to me that most of the time variables that you put in this method will not be used local to int(), so that is just fine. What am I missing?

Comment: Use assignment instead of a short variable declaration in the init function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword `:=` is shorthand for "assign to new variable"-- Go lets you shadow old variables with new variables in deeper scopes.

`foo` exists within the global scope, but you've created a new `foo` inside the `init()` scope-- therefore, inside of `init()`, `foo` shadows the global `foo`.

Furthermore, Go complains about unused variables in local scopes. In this case, your `foo` in `init()` is unused.

So, to walk over this,

- You defined `foo` in the global scope
- You entered `init()`, and then defined a `foo` within `init()`, shadowing the global `foo`
- You did not use the local variable `foo`.

If you want to set the global foo, use `=`, not `:=`, as `:=` creates a new variable.

Answer (score 4):

That just creates a local variable named "foo" inside the method. You need to assign the string to the already declared var at the module scope via foo = "bar".

Answer (score 1):

In Go `foo:="bar"` is a short assignment statement that can be used in a function in place of a `var` declaration.

So essentially what you have done is declare a new `foo` variable inside the `init` method instead of used the global `foo`